# I can't get new modules to load in metasploit

Tags: metasploit

I have been trying to load a new module in MS. I followed the instructions and done a git clone [address of files]. I then copied the new files into /root/.msf4/modules/exploits/windows/smb and into /usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/windows/smb and issued reload_all and restarted msfconsole but still no matter what way i try it it still says:

```
msf > use exploits/windows/smb/eternalblue_doublepulsar
[-] Failed to load module: exploits/windows/smb/eternalblue_doublepulsar
msf >
```

i tried every combo including:
use exploit/windows/smb/eternalblue_doublepulsar
use exploits/windows/smb/eternalblue_doublepulsar
use exploit/windows/smb/eternalblue_doublepulsar.rb
use exploits/windows/smb/eternalblue_doublepulsar.rb

and also the same with other downloadable modules

i double checked the file path, i tried:
chmod 644 eternalblue_doublepulsar.rb
to make the perms the same as the other modules in the same folder
which work btw

any help would be much appreciated
Thank you
Damian Moore

Answer (score 0):

Did u clone the exploit from https://github.com/ElevenPaths/Eternalblue-Doublepulsar-Metasploit? a way to debug, choose an exploit which already exists in the folder(such as ms08_067_netapi.rb),change the name to eternalblue_doublepulsar,and reload_all,run it and see what will be happened.