# My metasploit module(s) not found/loading

Tags: metasploit

Any custom metasploit module I create isn't getting loaded.

I tried both of these demos:

https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/building-module/ https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/wiki/Loading-External-Modules

and got the same result that the modules were NOT found.

Before posting here, I checked these out:

https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?28940-Metasploit-modules-not-loading! 
https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/modules-and-locations

and from SO:

[I can't get new modules to load in metasploit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44191341/i-cant-get-new-modules-to-load-in-metasploit)
[How to add module in Metasploit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48285326/how-to-add-module-in-metasploit)

no help

Just working with the github example, on the Kali host, I do indeed have the file in the right location (according to the demo):

```
root@kali:~/.msf4/modules/exploits/test# ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 19 13:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Mar 19 13:58 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9 Mar 19 13:59 test_module.rb
```

I then ran `reload_all` and when using this command:

`use exploit/test/test_module` it returns with `Failed to load module`.

I also tried to manually load that path and it failed too:

```
msf > loadpath ~/.msf4/modules/
Loaded 0 modules:
```

Answer (score 3):

Posting the answer for anyone who may come across this.  I'm kinda new to this; didn't know where metasploit info gets logged.

It's in:   ~/.msf4/logs/framework.log

The log told me I had a syntax error... must have happened from copying and pasting the text from the browser.  Cleaned that up and everything works.

Comment: This solved it for me too, exact same issue, but there was no indication of what was wrong outside of that log that I could see.